# .js - raphael click delete path

Tags: javascript, click, raphael

I have no idea anymore how to do it. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work. I bet it's some easy dumb mistake I do, but will see.

I am creating this path (trA - which works just fine) and what I need is, is either remove a path trA after clicking on span #clean, or remove it after second click on span #tA. I don't mind which one will it be, but I just need to remove the path after the click. The second version would be of course better.

HTML:

```
<span class="trasa red" id="tA">TRASA A</span>
<span class="trasa" id="clean">CLEAN</span>
```

.js

```
document.getElementById('tA').addEventListener('click', function() {
   var trA = rsr.path("M 34,33 L55,43 L222,78 L214,152 L144,150 L152,156 L205,255");
   trA.attr({'stroke': 'red', 'stroke-width': '2'});
}, false);


document.getElementById('clean').addEventListener('click', function() {
   trA.remove();
}, false);
```

THX for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trA variable isn't in scope for the 2nd function, as it was defined in function scope of your first handler.

Try this..

```
var trA;
document.getElementById('tA').addEventListener('click', function() {
   trA = rsr.path("M 34,33 L55,43 L222,78 L214,152 L144,150 L152,156 L205,255");
   trA.attr({'stroke': 'red', 'stroke-width': '2'});
}, false);


document.getElementById('clean').addEventListener('click', function() {
   trA.remove();
}, false);
```

Comment: ohhh my god, works like a charm. Thank you. I knew it was some stupidity.

Comment: :) Make sure you keep an eye on your browser console as well, as some errors like that may give you a clue.